# How to solve this ODE $(y - x y^2) dx - (x + x^2 y) dy =0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i have to solve this ODE: $(y - x y^2) dx - (x + x^2 y) dy =0$
I have tried by many methods (integrating factor,separation of variables, etc..  ) but i cant solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(y - x y^2) dx - (x + x^2 y) dy =0\to\\ydx-xdy-xy(ydx+xdy)=0\to \\y^2d({x\over y})=xyd(xy)$$by defining $v={x\over y}$ and $u=xy$ we obtain:$${u\over v}dv=udu\to \\{dv\over v}=du\to \\\ln v=u+C_1\to\\ v=Ce^u\quad,\quad C>0\to \\x=Cye^{x y}\quad,\quad C>0$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider $$(y - x y^2)  - (x + x^2 y)\, y' =0$$
and make $y=\frac z x$ . This should give
$$\frac{2 z}{x}-(z+1) z'=0$$ which does not look too bad.

Just for your curiosity, there is even an analytical solution $z(x)$ which uses a special function.

Answer (score 0):

Integrating factor is
$$\mu=\frac{1}{xy}.$$
Solution:
$$\log{\left( \frac{x}{y}\right) }-x y=C.$$